# Qt Creator on Mac and boost libraries

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt-creator

I am running QtCreator on Mac... I want to start working on boost libraries ... So, I installed boost libraries using

```
brew install boost
```

After that I created a small boost hallo world program and made the changes in .pro file as follows

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

unix:INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1/include/"
unix:LIBPATH += "-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1/lib/"

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += \
-lboost_date_time \
-lboost_filesystem \
-lboost_program_options \
-lboost_regex \
-lboost_signals \
-lboost_system
```

I am still unable to build... What could be the reason? Please suggest me what could be the possible mistake...

The errors are

```
library not found for -lboost_data_time
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: what are the error messages?, you need to run qmake first before you can build with the modified .pro.

Comment: :-1: error: library not found for -lboost_regex

Comment: you need to compile the binaries of boost (or double check that the ones you need are present)

Comment: I think it's not necessary as "brew" installs the precompiled development libraries of boost ... I am not sure if I am right

Comment: double check your lib folder anyway and see if they exist, often they have a suffix depending on the release/multithreaded ness of the compilation process

Comment: DAMARLAs-MacBook-Air:~ damarla$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1/lib/
libboost_atomic-mt.a   libboost_graph-mt.a   libboost_math_c99f.a   libboost_program_options.a  libboost_system.a
libboost_atomic-mt.dylib  libboost_graph-mt.dylib   libboost_math_c99f.dylib  libboost_program_options.dylib  libboost_system.dylib
libboost_chrono-mt.a   libboost_graph.a   libboost_math_c99l-mt.a   libboost_python-mt.a   libboost_test_exec_monitor-mt.a
libboost_chrono-mt.dylib  libboost_graph.dylib   libboost_math_c99l-mt.dylib  libboost_python-mt.dylib  libboost_test_exec_monitor.a

Comment: The libraries are present

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taking a bit from Uflex's answer, as he missed something.
So keep the same code:

```
//make sure that there is a boost folder in your boost include directory
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
auto start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for ( long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
        std::sqrt( 123.456L ); // burn some time

    auto sec = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "took " << sec.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But lets change his .pro a bit:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

macx {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

    _BOOST_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1
    INCLUDEPATH += "$${_BOOST_PATH}/include/"
    LIBS += -L$${_BOOST_PATH}/lib
    ## Use only one of these:
    LIBS += -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_system # using dynamic lib (not sure if you need that "-mt" at the end or not)
    #LIBS += $${_BOOST_PATH}/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.a # using static lib
}
```

The only thing I have added to this was the boost system( -lboost_system )
That should solve the issue with his original version causing the undefined symbols, and allow you to add your other libraries.

Such as -lboost_date_time, which for me worked perfectly with the brew install.

Granted, my path is actually: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2

Answer (score 0):

Boost libraries are modularized, you just need to link against the libraries that you are using. Some libraries are [header only](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries), so you don't need to do anything, having boost reachable in your path is enough.

You can try to compile this:

```
//make sure that there is a boost folder in your boost include directory
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    auto start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for ( long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
        std::sqrt( 123.456L ); // burn some time

    auto sec = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "took " << sec.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And in the .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

macx {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

    _BOOST_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1
    INCLUDEPATH += "$${_BOOST_PATH}/include/"
    LIBS += -L$${_BOOST_PATH}/lib
    ## Use only one of these:
    LIBS += -lboost_chrono-mt # using dynamic lib (not sure if you need that "-mt" at the end or not)
    #LIBS += $${_BOOST_PATH}/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.a # using static lib
}
```

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init3 in main.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [HalloWorld-Boost] Error 1
20:11:47: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.

Comment: I did understand the changes you made but I still get the adobe compilation errors.