# Qt and Boost (installed through Homebrew) result in Qt compile errors

Tags: qt, boost, homebrew

I am in the exact situation described in this question ([Qt Creator on Mac and boost libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134937/qt-creator-on-mac-and-boost-libraries)) but the accepted answer is not working for me. I've searched around and tried all the suggestions I've found but I still end up with errors

**Environment:**

- OSX 10.9.5
- Qt 5.5.1 - Qt Creator 3.5.1 - installed using the Qt
  installer
- Boost 1.59.0 – installed through Homebrew
- Am able to compile and run Qt apps

After creating a new Qt test application, when I add the `Boost` information to the .pro file (shown below) as described in the question linked above, I end up with very confusing compile errors within the Qt classes. I don't get it. Does anyone understand the conflict and know how to resolve this – I've been at it for hours now.

[image]

```
QT   += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = audiowaveform_test
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

macx {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

    _BOOST_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0
    INCLUDEPATH += "$${_BOOST_PATH}/include/"
    LIBS += -L$${_BOOST_PATH}/lib
    ## Use only one of these:
    LIBS += -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_system # using dynamic lib (not sure if you need that "-mt" at the end or not)
    #LIBS += $${_BOOST_PATH}/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.a # using static lib
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by changing this line in the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

to this:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

If someone can explain what `-std` means in compiler speak, I would appreciate it. Does it mean that *everything* should be compiled as `c++11`?

Comment: It sounds like your compiler doesn't accept `-std=c++11`. By changing to `CONFIG += c++11` you're letting Qt set the relevant C++11 flag for your compiler. The `compile output` in QtCreator will show you the flag that it set.